# Java.util.Timer - Process continue when main thread end

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, process

I have this simple code using `util.Timer`

```
public class CheckDBAccessListOpenAccesses extends TimerTask {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CheckDBAccessListOpenAccesses object = new CheckDBAccessListOpenAccesses();
    }

    private CheckDBAccessListOpenAccesses() {

        System.out.println("Start");
        Timer whatAccessAreOpen = new Timer();
        whatAccessAreOpen.scheduleAtFixedRate(this,  TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1), TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1));
        Thread.sleep(100*60*1000);
        System.out.println("finish");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
         System.out.println("one minute");
    }

}
```

When I run the code, the process runs forever.
I want the process to stop when the main Thread ends. Why is the Timer keeps the process alive? is there a way to prevent it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java has two types of Threads: user threads and daemon threads. User threads prevent the JVM from terminating, daemon threads do not. By default, a Timer is backed by a user thread, unless it is specified to run as a daemon in the constructor.

To prevent the Timer from keeping the process alive, instantiate the Timer with:

```
new Timer (true)
```

See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#Timer-boolean-

Answer (score 2):

Well, that's in the `Timer`'s API.

The [Timer#scheduleAtFixedRate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.util.TimerTask,%20java.util.Date,%20long%29) method:

> Schedules the specified task for repeated fixed-rate execution, beginning at the specified time. Subsequent executions take place at approximately regular intervals, separated by the specified period.
>
> [...]

You may want to use [Timer#schedule](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20java.util.Date%29) for one-shot operations, instead.

Otherwise, and what you likely really want, is to have the `Timer` object visible from your main thread, so you can just invoke [Timer#cancel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#cancel%28%29) on it when you wish to cancel the scheduled operation, e.g. when your main thread terminates.

Comment: thank you for the answer, do you mean Timer#schedule will run in the same thread as the main function?

Comment: @NoIdeaForName you're welcome. The documentation isn't specific but it's obvious that the `schedule` method will not run in the same thread as the invoking thread, otherwise it would block - which wouldn't be very useful! Likely what you want is the instance of your `Timer` to be visible in the main thread, so you can invoke `cancel` when you're done.